# Как правильно сформировать Cmake для компиляции кода на Си в Clion

Tags: c, clion, gtk, glade

В **Glade** получил **xml** содержащий объекты для **gtk**, чтобы работать с ними на си.
Начал использовать **Clion**. Проблема с составлением `Cmakelist.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(Habr_example C)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)

find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
pkg_check_modules(GTK3 REQUIRED gtk+-3.0)
set(Rdynamic "-rdynamic")

include_directories(${GTK3_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${GTK3_LIBRARY_DIRS})

add_definitions(${GTK3_CFLAGS_OTHER} ${Rdynamic})

add_executable(Habr_example main.c)
target_link_libraries(Habr_example ${GTK3_LIBRARIES})
```

Компиляция проходит успешно, но при запуске программы получаю ошибку:

> (Habr_example:9196): Gtk-WARNING **: 20:41:27.007: Could not find
>   signal handler 'helloworld'.  Did you compile with -rdynamic?

До этого работал в  **SublimeText 3**. Тот же проект успешно компилировался и запускался используя:

```
gcc -g -o ${file_base_name} $file_name `pkg-config gtk+-3.0 --cflags --libs` -Wall -Wextra -rdynamic
```

Объясните, пожалуйста, чего не хватает в  `Cmakelist.txt`?
Так же будет приятно, если кто-нибудь пояснит простым языком о роли   `-rdynamics` при компиляции в данном случае и в целом.

Answer (score 0):

> кто-нибудь пояснит простым языком о роли *-rdynamics*

Читаем доку:

```
-rdynamic

    Pass the flag -export-dynamic to the ELF linker, on targets that support it.
This instructs the linker to add all symbols, not only used ones, to the dynamic
symbol table. This option is needed for some uses of dlopen or to allow obtaining
backtraces from within a program.
```

Проще говоря, эта опция нужна в двух случаях:

1. Вы собираетесь распечатывать *backtraces* при возникновении ошибки.
2. Линкуемый модуль - разделяемая библиотека (*.so)

Похоже, что у Вас что-то не в порядке с динамической линковкой. Вы используете ключ *${Rdynamic}* но функция *helloworld* не может быть найдена во время выполнения программы. Проверьте всё, что связано с линковкой. Там ведь важен даже порядок перечисления модулей при линковке.